# Covariance in generic collections

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, covariance, generic-collections

I would like to do this

```
List<anotherclass> ls = new List<anotherclass> {new anotherclass{Name = "me"}};    
myGrid.ItemSource = ls;
```

at some other place

```
var d = myGrid.ItemSource as IEnumerable<Object>;    
var e = d as ICollection<dynamic>;
e.Add(new anotherclass());
```

I need to access the itemsource at different areas of the program. I need to add items to the List without compile time type information. Casting to IEnumerable works, but because  I need to add items to the collection I need more than that, hence trying to cast it to a collection.

How can it be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>` implements [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.ilist.aspx). So as long as you're sure you're adding the right type of object, you can use the `Add` method of this interface:

```
var d = (IList)myGrid.ItemSource;        
d.Add(new anotherclass());
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is not: "Why does it work?", because, in fact, it doesn't work. It compiles but it will throw a `NullReferenceException`.
`d as ICollection<dynamic>` will return `null` because an `List<anotherclass>` isn't an `ICollection<dynamic>` but an `ICollection<anotherclass>` and `ICollection<T>` is not covariant.

The solution already has been provided by [KooKiz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13121461/572644).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var d =(List<anotherclass>) myGrid.ItemSource;
d.Add(new anotherclass());
```

I think it is better to do a direct cast. If you use as it will throw a nullreferenceException when trying to add. It is better to have the invalidCastException that better describes what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know the actual type at the point of adding

Comment: But you know you want to add an instance of anotherclass.

Comment: No, the point is The Itemssource is set in some part of the program and any classes can be inside it. At one part of the application I wanted to write a generic routine to handle the itemsource regardless on the type of object contained inside it.